# When was the First T20 match played?

Tags: cricket, history, trivia

When was the first Official (not friendly) T-20 match played?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty20#Origins) the first ever T20 match was played on 13th June, 2003 between [Durham and Nottinghamshire](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/304744.html) at Chester-le-Street.

The first international T20 match was played on 17th February, 2005 between [Australia and New Zealand](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/current/match/211048.html) at Eden Park, Auckland.

Answer (score -5):

I am sure I saw a Lancshire Yorshire T20 friendly at Old Trafford before the competition started properly in 2003. Can't find an evidence of it yet though.

Comment: see the revised question